# This $\int_{- \frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{e^{in x}dx}{1+\tan^m(x)}$ integral: does a closed form exist?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, fourier-series

$$\int_{- \frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{e^{in x}dx}{1+\tan^m(x)}$$

Does a closed form for the above exist, ideally for $n,m\in\mathbb{C}$ (most bounds probably removed at one point using analystic continuation)?  The answer will probably have singularities whenever $\exists x \in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x^m=-1$, i.e. $m$ is an odd integer.

Closed forms exist for [similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718610/ramanujans-well-known-integral-int-frac-pi2-frac-pi2-cos-xm) [integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605673/integrate-int-0-pi-2-frac11-tan-alphax-mathrmdx), which is why I had hope in the answer existing. I came across this when trying to construct the Fourier series for $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+\tan^m(x)}$.