# Evaluating the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(1-ix)^{n-s_1}}{(1+ix)^{n+s_2}} dx$.

Tags: integration, contour-integration, gamma-function, complex-integration

How can one show that for $s_1,s_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ $$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(1-ix)^{n-s_1}}{(1+ix)^{n+s_2}}  dx = &   2\sin(\pi(n+s_2))2^{1-s_1-s_2} \Gamma(1-n-s_2)\Gamma(s_1+s_2-1)/ \Gamma(s_1-n)  & \\ = & 2^{2-s_1-s_2}\pi \Gamma(s_1+s_2-1)/[\Gamma(n+s_2)\Gamma(s_1-n)]. 
\end{aligned} 
$$

If I recall correctly this could be done with complex analysis noting that the integral is equal to
$$
\int_{C} \frac{(1-ix)^{n-s_1}}{(1+ix)^{n+s_2}}  dx,
$$

where $C$ starts from $+i \infty$ along the imaginary axis and goes around $i$ once in a small circle (positive direction) and then goes back to $+i\infty$.

However this doesn't help me since I don't know how we can deform the contour to $C$ and to evaluate this contour integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One considers the complex contour integral

$$\oint_C dz \frac{(1-i z)^{n-s_1}}{(1+i z)^{n+s_2}} $$

where $C$ is a semicircle of radius $R$ in the upper half plane, with a detour along either side of the imaginary axis and around the branch point $z=i$ with a circle of radius $\epsilon$.  We take as a branch cut the ray $\operatorname{Re}{z} =0$, $\operatorname{Im}{z} \gt 1$.  The contour integral is zero by Cauchy's theorem.  Writing the contour integral out, we get

$$\int_{-R}^R dx \frac{(1-i x)^{n-s_1}}{(1+i x)^{n+s_2}} + i R \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{(1-i R e^{i \theta})^{n-s_1}}{(1+i R e^{i \theta})^{n+s_2}} \\ + i \int_R^{1+\epsilon} dy \, \frac{(1+y)^{n-s_1}}{(1-y)_+^{n+s_2}} + i \epsilon \int_{\pi/2}^{-3 \pi/2} d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{(2-i \epsilon e^{i \phi})^{n-s_1}}{(i \epsilon e^{i \phi})^{n+s_2}} \\+ i \int_{1+\epsilon}^R dy \, \frac{(1+y)^{n-s_1}}{(1-y)_-^{n+s_2}} + i R \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{(1-i R e^{i \theta})^{n-s_1}}{(1+i R e^{i \theta})^{n+s_2}} = 0 $$

In the third and fifth intgerals, I use the subscripts $\pm$ to denote the effect of the different sides of the branch cut on the quantity that subscript modifies.  That is, $(1-y)_+^{n+s_2} = e^{i \pi (n+s_2)} (y-1)^{n+s_2}$ and $(1-y)_-^{n+s_2} = e^{-i \pi (n+s_2)} (y-1)^{n+s_2}$.

We take the limits as $R \to \infty$ and $\epsilon \to 0$.  Thus, we assume that $s_1$ and $s_2$ are defined such that the second and sixth integrals vanish in this limit, i.e., $\operatorname{Re}{(s_1+s_2)} \gt 1$.  Also, the fourth integral vanishes when $\operatorname{Re}{(n+s_2)} \lt 1$, which we will assume to be the case.  Thus, we have,

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{(1-i x)^{n-s_1}}{(1+i x)^{n+s_2}} &= -i \int_{\infty}^1 dy \frac{(y+1)^{n-s_1}}{(y-1)^{n+s_2} e^{i \pi (n+s_2)}} -i \int_1^{\infty} dy \frac{(y+1)^{n-s_1}}{(y-1)^{n+s_2} e^{-i \pi (n+s_2)}}\\ &= i (-2 i \sin{[\pi (n+s_2)]})  \int_1^{\infty} dy \frac{(y+1)^{n-s_1}}{(y-1)^{n+s_2}}\\ &=  2 \sin{[\pi (n+s_2)]} \int_0^{\infty} dy \, y^{-(n+s_2)} (y+2)^{n-s_1}\\ &= 2^{2-s_1-s_2} \sin{[\pi (n+s_2)]} \int_0^{\infty} dy \, y^{-(n+s_2)} (y+1)^{n-s_1}\\ &= 2^{2-s_1-s_2} \sin{[\pi (n+s_2)]} \int_1^{\infty} dy \, (y-1)^{-(n+s_2)} y^{n-s_1}\\&= 2^{2-s_1-s_2} \sin{[\pi (n+s_2)]} \int_0^1 du \, u^{s_1+s_2-2} (1-u)^{-(n+s_2)} \end{align}$$

We recognize that last integral as a beta integral.  Thus, we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{(1-i x)^{n-s_1}}{(1+i x)^{n+s_2}} = 2^{2-s_1-s_2} \sin{[\pi (n+s_2)]} \frac{\Gamma(s_1+s_2-1) \Gamma(1-n-s_2)}{\Gamma(s_1-n)} $$

Finally, using the reflection formula, i.e., $\pi/\sin{(\pi z)} = \Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z)$, we get the result we seek in final form:

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{(1-i x)^{n-s_1}}{(1+i x)^{n+s_2}} = \frac{4 \pi \, \Gamma(s_1+s_2-1)}{2^{s_1+s_2} \Gamma(s_1-n) \Gamma(n+s_2)} $$

This is, as mentioned above, subject to the constraints $\operatorname{Re}{(s_1+s_2)} \gt 1$ and $\operatorname{Re}{(n+s_2)} \lt 1$.

**ADDENUDUM**

[Here is a problem](http://residuetheorem.com/2015/09/11/fascinating-fourier-transform/) that is both a special case and a little bit of a generalization at the same time.  Note that there are two branch points rather than the single one here.

**ADDENUDUM II**
I made an error in the integral about the small circle about the branch point; there, $z=i+\epsilon \, e^{i \phi}$.  That error has been corrected and there is now an additional constraint that must be satisfied by the parameters $n$ and $s_2$ for the posted result to remain valid.

Comment: It seems that the second condition $Re(n+s_2)<1$ isn't needed in the end because we can drop that by analytic continuation. But  yes we need to assume it at first.

Answer (score 2):

The substitution $\;x=\tan\theta\;$ makes the integral \begin{align}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\Big(\frac{\cos\theta-i\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\Big)^{n-s_1}\Big(\frac{\cos\theta}{\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}\Big)^{n+s_2}\sec^2\theta\;d\theta&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}e^{-i(n-s_1)\theta}e^{-i(n+s_2)\theta}\cos^{s_1+s_2-2}\theta\;d\theta\\
&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}e^{-i(2n+s_2-s_1)\theta}\cos^{s_1+s_2-2}\theta\;d\theta\tag{$\star$}
\end{align}
[This link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718610/ramanujans-well-known-integral-int-frac-pi2-frac-pi2-cos-xm?rq=1) shows how to solve $(\star)$.

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\pars{1 - \ic x}^{n - s_{1}} \over \pars{1 + \ic x}^{n + s_{2}}}\,\dd x =
-\ic\int_{-\infty\,\ic}^{\infty\,\ic}
{\pars{1 - x}^{n - s_{1}} \over \pars{1 + x}^{n + s_{2}}}\,\dd x =
-\ic\int_{1 - \infty\,\ic}^{1 + \infty\,\ic}
{\pars{2 - x}^{n - s_{1}} \over x^{n + s_{2}}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-2\ic\int_{1 - \infty\,\ic}^{1 + \infty\,\ic}
{2^{n - s_{1}}\pars{1 - x/2}^{n - s_{1}} \over
2^{n + s_{2}}\pars{x/2}^{n + s_{2}}}\,{\dd x \over 2}
\\[5mm] = &\
-2^{-s_{1} - s_{2} + 1}\ \ic
\color{#44f}{\int_{1/2 - \infty\,\ic}^{1/2 + \infty\,\ic}
x^{-n - s_{2}}\,\pars{1 - x}^{n - s_{1}}\,\dd x}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

> I'll take the principal branch of $\ds{z^{-n - s_{2}}}$ and the branch-cut of
>   $\ds{\pars{1 - z}^{n - s_{1}}}$ 'along' $\ds{\left[1,\infty\right)}$ with
>   $\ds{0 < \,\mrm{arg}\pars{1 - z} < 2\pi}$. The integration is performed by closing the contour in a 'big semicircle' $\ds{\,\mc{C}_{R}}$ of radius $\ds{R}$ with $\ds{\Re\pars{z} < {1 \over 2}}$. The integration along $\ds{\,\mc{C}_{R}}$ vanishes out, when $\ds{R \to \infty}$, whenever
>   $\ds{\pars{~\Re\pars{-s_{1} - s_{2} + 1} < 0 \implies
> \Re\pars{s_{1} + s_{2} > 1}~}}$

\begin{align}
&\color{#44f}{\int_{1/2 - \infty\,\ic}^{1/2 + \infty\,\ic}
x^{-n - s_{2}}\,\pars{1 - x}^{n - s_{1}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim} &\
-\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}\pars{-x}^{-n - s_{2}}
\exp\pars{\ic\pi\pars{-n - s_{2}}}\pars{1 - x}^{n - s_{1}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & -
\int_{\pi}^{-\pi}\epsilon^{-n - s_{2}}\exp\pars{\ic\theta\pars{-n - s_{2}}}
\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] & -
\int_{-\epsilon}^{-\infty}\pars{-x}^{-n - s_{2}}
\exp\pars{-\ic\pi\pars{-n - s_{2}}}\pars{1 - x}^{n - s_{1}}\,\dd x
\\[1cm] = &\
-\pars{-1}^{n}\exp\pars{-\ic\pi s_{2}}\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}x^{-n - s_{2}}
\pars{1 + x}^{n - s_{1}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & -
2\ic\,\pars{-1}^{n}\,{\sin\pars{\pi s_{2}} \over n + s_{2} - 1}\,
\epsilon^{-n - s_{2} + 1}
\\[5mm] & +
\pars{-1}^{n}\exp\pars{\ic\pi s_{2}}\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}x^{-n - s_{2}}
\pars{1 + x}^{n - s_{1}}\,\dd x
\\[1cm] = &\
2\ic\pars{-1}^{n}\sin\pars{\pi s_{2}}\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}x^{-n - s_{2}}
\pars{1 + x}^{n - s_{1}}\,\dd x -
2\ic\,\pars{-1}^{n}\,{\sin\pars{\pi s_{2}} \over n + s_{2} - 1}\,
\epsilon^{-n - s_{2} + 1}
\\[1cm] = &\
2\ic\pars{-1}^{n}\sin\pars{\pi s_{2}}\,\times
\\[5mm] &\ \bracks{%
{\epsilon^{-n - s_{2} + 1}\pars{1 + \epsilon}^{n - s_{1}} \over n + s_{2} - 1} -
{1 \over -n - s_{2} + 1}\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}x^{-n - s_{2} + 1}
\pars{n - s_{1}}\pars{1 + x}^{n - s_{1} - 1}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & -
2\ic\,\pars{-1}^{n}\,{\sin\pars{\pi s_{2}} \over n + s_{2} - 1}\,
\epsilon^{-n - s_{2} + 1}
\\[1cm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\to} &\
2\ic\pars{-1}^{n}\sin\pars{\pi s_{2}}\,
{n - s_{1} \over n + s_{2} - 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{-n - s_{2} + 1} \over \pars{1 + x}^{s_{1} -n + 1}}\,\dd x\label{2}\tag{2}
\\[5mm] = &\
-2\ic\pars{-1}^{n}\,{\sin\pars{\pi s_{2}} \over n + s_{2} - 1}\,
\Gamma\pars{2 - n - s_{2}}\,{s_{1} - n \over \Gamma\pars{s_{1} - n + 1}}
\,\Gamma\pars{s_{1} + s_{2} - 1}
\\[1cm] = &\
-2\ic\pars{-1}^{n}\,{\sin\pars{\pi s_{2}} \over n + s_{2} - 1}\,
{\pi \over \Gamma\pars{-1 + n + s_{2}}\sin\pars{\pi\bracks{-1 + n + s_{2}}}}
\,{1 \over \Gamma\pars{s_{1} - n}}
\\[5mm] & \Gamma\pars{s_{1} + s_{2} - 1}
\\[1cm] = &\
-2\ic\pars{-1}^{n}\,\sin\pars{\pi s_{2}}\,
{\pi \over \Gamma\pars{n + s_{2}}\pars{-1}^{n - 1}\sin\pars{\pi s_{2}}}
\,{1 \over \Gamma\pars{s_{1} - n}}\,\Gamma\pars{s_{1} + s_{2} - 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
2\pi\ic\,
{\Gamma\pars{s_{1} + s_{2} - 1} \over
\Gamma\pars{n + s_{2}}\Gamma\pars{s_{1} - n}}\label{3}\tag{3}
\end{align}
In the last steps, I used the $\ds{\Gamma}$*-Recurrence Property* and the *Euler Reflection Formula*. The integral in \eqref{2} is a well know
[Beta function integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties) which requires
\begin{align}
&\Re\pars{\bracks{-n - s_{2} + 1} + 1} > 0\,,\quad
\Re\pars{s_{1} + s_{2} - 1} > 0
\\[5mm] &
\implies
\Re\pars{s_{2} + n} < 2\ \mbox{and}\ \Re\pars{s_{1} + s_{2} > 1}
\end{align}

---

> With \eqref{1} and \eqref{3}:

\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\pars{1 - \ic x}^{n - s_{1}} \over \pars{1 + \ic x}^{n + s_{2}}}\,\dd x =
\pars{-2^{-s_{1} - s_{2} + 1}\ \ic}\bracks{%
2\pi\ic\,
{\Gamma\pars{s_{1} + s_{2} - 1} \over
\Gamma\pars{n + s_{2}}\Gamma\pars{s_{1} - n}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\ds{{4\pi \over 2^{s_{1} + s_{2}}}\,
{\Gamma\pars{s_{1} + s_{2} - 1} \over
\Gamma\pars{n + s_{2}}\Gamma\pars{s_{1} - n}}}}\,,\qquad
\Re\pars{s_{1} + s_{2}} > 1\,,\quad\Re\pars{s_{2} + n < 2}
\end{align}